# Understanding "Et que ce n’est pas chose étrange"

Tags: articles

The question is on the highlighted line of the *Moralité* to *Le petit chaperon rouge* as collected by Perrault.

> On voit ici que de jeunes enfants,
>   
> Surtout de jeunes filles
>   
> Belles, bien faites, et gentilles,
>   
> Font très mal d’écouter toute sorte de gens,
>   
> **Et que ce n’est pas chose étrange,**
>   
> S’il en est tant que le loup mange.
>   
> Je dis le loup, car tous les loups
>   
> Ne sont pas de la même sorte :
>   
> Il en est d’une humeur accorte,
>   
> Sans bruit, sans fiel et sans courroux,
>   
> Qui, privés, complaisants et doux,
>   
> Suivent les jeunes demoiselles
>   
> Jusque dans les maisons, jusque dans les ruelles.
>   
> Mais hélas ! qui ne sait que ces loups doucereux
>   
> De tous les loups sont les plus dangereux.

**Questions**

1. How do you say in today's French, "It is not a dog"?  "Ce n'est pas de chien" or "ce n'est pas chien" or something else?
2. How do you say in today's French, "It is not a strange thing"? "Ce n'est pas de chose étrange" or "ce n'est pas chose étrange"? If answers to 1 and 2 are different (one uses "pas de + noun" and the other "pas + noun") what accounts for the difference?
3. Assuming that today's form is "pas de + noun" for both 1 and 2, was "pas + noun" the usual form at the time of Perrault or is there some other explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. That would be: *Ce n'est pas un chien*; *de chien* would be used in *il n'y a pas de chien* (there is no dog), *du chien* in the dubious *ce n'est pas du chien* (that's not dog).
2. Standard French would be *Ce n'est pas une chose étrange* (*chose* is a regular sustantive). Poetical/literary might be *Ce n'est pas chose étrange* (*chose* is used here as an invariable word). See chose<sup>1</sup> and chose<sup>2</sup> in the [tlfi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chose).
3. Today's form is *pas un*. At the time of Perrault, the form without an article was probably more common but unlikely the usual one. In some cases, several forms are still possible:

> Il n'y avait pas homme plus heureux !
>
> Il n'y avait pas d'homme plus heureux !
>
> Il n'y avait pas un homme plus heureux !

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by "dubious"? Is it perhaps when people aren't sure what it is and someone is offering that, at any rate, it is not a dog?

Comment: By dubious, I mean this sentence would essentially be used when wondering what kind of meat is something. Think *That's not chicken* vs *That's not a chicken*.

Comment: I think the reason is that *chose* was used as pronoun very earlier on, like “something”, or “quelque chose” in modern French.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Indeed, answer updated. Thanks.

Comment: Am I to understand that *plus heureux* is making two more forms available? That is to say, am I to understand: 1. There is only one way to say that there was no dog or no man, i.e. "il n'y a pas de chien" and "il n'y a pas d'homme." 2. But when the noun is modified by something like *plus heureux* then we get two more acceptable forms? Or do we get three forms only when the thing is *homme*? What is doing the trick?